# Drupal 7 User Edit White Screen Page?

Tags: drupal, admin, edit

In Drupal 7, when i goto `http://....com/admin/people` and then click `Edit` on any user there, then a blank white screen is appearing.

This user edit url is like: `http://......com/user/1234/edit?destination=admin/people`

Not even a line of error. Just blank white.
What should i do?

Comment: See http://drupal.org/node/158043/about the "white screen of death"

Answer (score 1):

You can go to /admin/reports/dblog just after you hit the white screen, you should see the error in that report.

This will help you to find the error that is breaking the page.

Comment: Are you referring to a file? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be late, but it helped me. Most times a module causes WSOD, I couldn't just disable modules to test which it was, since I may have lost data in the process. What I did was to edit this function in module.inc

```
function module_invoke_all($hook) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  // Remove $hook from the arguments.
  unset($args[0]);
  $return = array();
  foreach (module_implements($hook) as $module) {

        print "Starting loading $module <br />";

        $function = $module . '_' . $hook;
        if (function_exists($function)) {
          $result = call_user_func_array($function, $args);
          if (isset($result) && is_array($result)) {
            $return = array_merge_recursive($return, $result);
          }
          elseif (isset($result)) {
            $return[] = $result;
          }
        }

        print "Finished loading $module <br />";

  }

  return $return;
}
```

And I added those 2 print statements in the code above, then refresh the page, the module which didn't reach the "Finish loading $module" statement is the one with the problem... it was devel in my case.

After finding the module, you can go into the system table and look for that module, set it's status = 0 and bootstrap = 0 or run the query:

```
UPDATE system SET status = 0, bootstrap = 0 WHERE name = 'module_name' LIMIT 1
```